# Add scrollbar to Groupbox containing Thumbail images

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Here is My Designer.cs code.**

```
this.gbFacets.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(590, 69);
this.gbFacets.Name = "gbFacets";
this.gbFacets.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 355);
this.gbFacets.TabIndex = 7;
this.gbFacets.TabStop = false;
this.gbFacets.Text = "Facets Found";
this.gbFacets.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.gbFacets_Enter);
```

**here is my Formmain code**

```
private void AddFacetsToPictureBoxes(List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes)
{
    foreach (var pic in pictureBoxes)
        this.gbFacets.Controls.Add(pic);
}
```

i got the pics added to Groupbox but if no of pics increases then, it shows only some pics. so please tell me how can i make this groupbox scrollable to view all pics.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the groupbox doesn't have a scrollable property, add your images to a panel instead and set the scrollable property.

Then have the panel fill the groupbox.

Edit: something like this

```
private void AddPicturesToGroupBox(List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes)
{
    Panel myPanel = new Panel();
    myPanel.Dockstyle = Dockstyle.Fill;
    myPanel.AutoScroll = true; //this allows the panel to display scrollbars when it needs to

    foreach (var pic in pictureBoxes)
    {
        myPanel.Controls.Add(pic); //put your pictures onto the panel
    }

    this.gbFacets.Controls.Clear();
    this.gbFacets.Controls.Add(myPanel); //put your panel inside the Groupbox
}
```

Comment: can u please share me links or code because i am completely new to the .net, so please do needful.

Comment: replace groupbox by a panel and make autoscroll property true,Or you may go for Hscrollbar,vscrollbar